# How do I hide autocmd status messages?

Tags: vimperator

I would like to silence the following status message.

```
Executing LocationChange Auto commands for ".*"
```

I get it on every page.

I have the following autocmd

```
autocmd LocationChange .* js modes.passAllKeys = /duolingo\.com/.test(buffer.URL)
```

Comment: `set verbose=0` doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [patch](https://code.google.com/p/vimperator-labs/issues/detail?id=679) for this, presumably pending review, which provides a `verbose` option you can set to false. The `verbose` option in the official builds takes an integer and doesn't seem to work. d-:

I patched the .xpi myself by hand (to practice techniques in vim and midnight commander). I don't guarantee I didn't make any mistakes, but it works for me. Get it [here](http://nejtiwspiker.pl/vimperator+verbose-patch.xpi) if you want to try.